# Register Service at Runtime via DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core and want to add a service to the IServiceProvider at runtime, so it can be used across the application via DI.

For instance, a simple example would be that the user goes to the settings controller and changes an authentication setting from "On" to "Off". In that instance I would like to replace the service that was registered at runtime.

Psuedo Code in the Settings Controller:

```
if(settings.Authentication == false)
{
     services.Remove(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>());
     services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IAuthenticationService, NoAuthService>());
}
else
{
     services.Remove(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IAuthenticationService, NoAuthService>
     services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>());
}
```

This logic works fine when I am doing it in my Startup.cs because the IServiceCollection has not been built into a IServiceProvider. However, I want to be able to do this after the Startup has already executed. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 21):

Instead of registering/removing service at runtime, I would create a service factory that decides the right service at runtime.

```
services.AddTransient<AuthenticationService>();
services.AddTransient<NoAuthService>();
services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationServiceFactory, AuthenticationServiceFactory>();
```

AuthenticationServiceFactory.cs

```
public class AuthenticationServiceFactory: IAuthenticationServiceFactory
{
     private readonly AuthenticationService _authenticationService;
     private readonly NoAuthService _noAuthService;
     public AuthenticationServiceFactory(AuthenticationService authenticationService, NoAuthService noAuthService)
     {
         _noAuthService = noAuthService;
         _authenticationService = authenticationService;
     }
     public IAuthenticationService GetAuthenticationService()
     {
          if(settings.Authentication == false)
          {
             return _noAuthService;
          }
          else
          {
              return _authenticationService;
          }
     }
}
```

Usage in a class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IAuthenticationServiceFactory _authenticationServiceFactory)
    {
        var authenticationService = _authenticationServiceFactory.GetAuthenticationService();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dawid with what authority do you say that this is "right approach"? Do you mean _"I would also do it like this"_? Why? Why is it a good answer?

Comment: Because it's better from Design Patterns point of view to register factory which hide some details (in this case getting some configuration/settings) and just provide right implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think this will work for me. I made my example extremely simple to illustrate the concept, but its not my *actual* problem. I have a modular system, where plugins can be "installed" at runtime and those plugins have services that they need to add to the ServiceCollection. My problem with this is I have no found a satisfactory way of adding those services at runtime. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @CodeCaster: Also the `ServiceCollection`shouldn't be changed after bootstrapping. The provider is built when then ASP.NET Core calls  `services.BuildServiceProvder()` (somewhere after `ConfigureServices` and before `Configure` call), changes happening to the `IServiceCollection` won't matter and another call to `.BuildServiceProvder()` just creates a new provider, with the old still being referenced in singleton services that happened before the change

Comment: @A.Fry: At runtime or not, you'll need an application restart to do this. Alternatively use an container which allows changing dependencies at runtime. As you can see here https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs the ServiceProvider is internal and has no public methods to mutate its `ServiceTable` collection

Comment: @Tseng - Thanks for your response. Do you know of any containers that allow dependency changes at runtime?

Comment: StructureMap, Light Inejct, pretty much most of them.

Comment: Good discussion. Coming from Unity, I was very surprised to learn that this is not enabled in ASP.NET containers.

Answer (score 0):

Something of the sort is possible in Autofac:

```
  private ILifetimeScope BeginChildScope()
  {
        return _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(x =>
        {
            x.Register<IAuthenticationService>(b => new AuthenticationService());
        });
  }
```

```
using (var childScope = BeginChildScope())
{
   // Do sth here
}
```

For .NET Core, I think this is the only possible solution atm.:
[Best strategy for creating a child container (or isolated scope) with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344278/best-strategy-for-creating-a-child-container-or-isolated-scope-with-microsoft/61344944#61344944)

Microsoft states unsupported features of ASP.NET Core DI here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement