# C# Dependency Injection Runtime (dynamic) registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am using VS 2017 and .NET Core. 
Using Dependency Injection, I would like to register my service at runtime, dynamically. My goal is to write instances of my service that implement the service interface inside of separate assemblies. The servicename/assembly name will then be added to some sort of configuration file (or db table).

My registration code would do something like this:

```
var ServiceTypeName = LoadServiceAssembly(AssemblyName); 

var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
 .AddTransient<IDILogger, "ConsoleDILogger">()  // <--- Goal
 .BuildServiceProvider();

var logger = serviceProvider.GetService(IDILogger);
```

Clearly, the AddTransient line will not work as such a method does not exist. It does, however, depict the idea. I want to register the type by a string name so that the loader application need not be recompiled everytime I add a new service type.

I cannot seem to find how to do this. Any suggestions would be welcome.

TIA

Comment: Why not use factory approach instead similar to what is proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654801/register-service-at-runtime-via-di ?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov, even in that example, a rebuild is necessary.  I don't see how one could provide the service instances as a plugin (assembly) - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @xgp Why can't you just use reflection to register the services inside of your startup class?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. A factory is how MVC 5 instantiates controllers with constructors it doesn't know about at compile time. The same is true of any [DI Friendly Framework](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/)

Comment: The case you described sounds like you need a plugin like system. Are you sure you want inject the "plugins" themselves rather than inject the service which knows where to load plugins from and how to interact with them?

Comment: Ok, gonna have to read up a bit on MVC 5 factories. Thanks for the comments all.  Helpful!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could read configured type from the settings, load the required type via reflection and register it in service collection:

```
//  Read from config
var assemblyPath = "...";
var typeName = "...";

var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
var loggerType = assembly.GetType(typeName);

var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddTransient(typeof(IDILogger), loggerType)
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<IDILogger>();
```

Such dynamic approach will not require any recompilation if you add or reconfigure new logger.

Answer (score 16):

That's obviously not possible as is, however, I used something similar to this in a project to avoid having to add each new type to the container:

```
var assembly = typeof(YourClass).Assembly; // I actually use Assembly.LoadFile with well-known names 
var types = assembly.ExportedTypes
   // filter types that are unrelated
   .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.IsPublic);

foreach (var type in types)
{
    // assume that we want to inject any class that implements an interface
    // whose name is the type's name prefixed with I
    services.AddScoped(type.GetInterface($"I{type.Name}"), type);
}
```

For your specific case, you could even make this shorter:

```
var type = assembly.ExportedTypes.First(x => x.Name == runtimeName);
services.AddScoped(typeof(IDILogger), type);
```

Comment: Excellent, basically a similar to post below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A very genuine question and with references to different answers by users, here's how I have solved in .NET 6

In program.cs added the following

```
//Register Service Modules to DI
builder.Services.IncludeServiceModule(builder.Configuration);
```

The called static function contains something like this

```
public static class ServiceModule
    { 
        public static IServiceCollection IncludeServiceModule(this IServiceCollection services,
         IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var appServices = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("FMDeBill.Service").GetTypes().Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith("Service") && s.IsInterface == false).ToList();
            foreach (var appService in appServices) 
                //services.AddTransient(appService.GetInterface($"I{appService.Name}"), appService); 
                services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(appService, appService, ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
            return services;
        } 
    }
```

The assembly name is the name of the project/assembly with services. Any service that is not an interface and ends with "Service" such as "CategoryService" is registered dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

### Auto-Register Dependency Injected Services in .NET Core

I wrote this method to auto-register all your `services` and `consumer` interfaces and classes at runtime for Dependency Injection by the IoC Container in .NET. All you have to do is add your interfaces and/or concrete classes to the *enums* lists below and the `RegisterServices()` method will add them for dependency injection in your .NET application. You can then add them to constructors or call them for dependency injection by .NET.

I chose to **load services from an enum** rather than say a JSON or other *configuration file* for **security reasons**. It also reduces dependencies and also locks the applications state, as well as forces development to lock the app to compilation. Developers must modify, add, remove service types and keep them closely coupled to the code. Changing a configuration file is too dangerous!

**LET'S BEGIN**

You will need to create two files then change the Startup.cs file in .NET.

Create a file called `ServiceList.cs` in .NET. This one is just a couple enums where you can add your list of types you want registered as services or consumers of services. If you have many classes that inherit from an Interface, just add lists of those in services. But it will accept concrete types, as well. But if you add an interface, the `RegisterServices` method below will locate all the child classes that implement the interface and register those, as well. The `RegisterServices()` method will grab them and register all your services with the IoC in .NET for you.

```
    // ADD SERVICES YOU WANT REGISTERED

    enum ServicesList
    {
        ISampleService,
        IAnotherService,
        AConcreteClassService
    }

    // ADD CONSUMERS YOU WANT REGISTERED

    enum ConsumersList
    {
        MyClass1,
        MyClass2,
        ISomeConsumerTypes
    }
```

Create a second class file called `RegisterServices.cs`. Add the following code. This is the main method that registers all the services listed in the enums above. It is called `RegisterServices.cs`.

```
    // REGISTER SERVICES
    // This will pull all the services you added to the ServicesList.cs
    // enum and try and register them with the Services Provider in .NET

    static class RegisterServices
    {
        // You can add the Logger here if you like.
        internal static void Start(IServiceCollection services, ILogger logger = null)
        {
          // Extract out all service enum values into a single list.
          List<string> allTypesToAdd = new List<string>();
          allTypesToAdd.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ServicesList)).ToList());
          allTypesToAdd.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ConsumersList)).ToList());

          // For now I am just getting the active running assembly
          Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
          IEnumerable<TypeInfo> assemblyTypes = assembly.DefinedTypes;

          List<string> missingEnumTypes = new List<string>();
          bool isTypeFound = false;

          // Loop through all services in the collection.
          // If your service type is not listed, add it.
          foreach (string typeToAdd in allTypesToAdd)
          {
            // Verify the enum type to add to the service collection exists in the application.
            isTypeFound = false;

            foreach (TypeInfo type in assemblyTypes)
            {
              if (type.Name == typeToAdd)
              {
                if (type.IsInterface)
                {
                  // Add the Interface and any concrete classes
                  // that are implementations of the parent interface.
                  var childOfInterface = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => type.AsType().IsAssignableFrom(t));
                  foreach (Type c in childOfInterface)
                  {
                    if (typeToAdd != c.Name)
                    {
                      // For now this just assumes you need a request
                      // scoped service lifetime services. Change as needed.
                      services.TryAddScoped(type.AsType(), c);
                      logger?.LogInformation(LogEventIDs.Information_General_ID, "INFORMATION: A new Service Class Was Added: services.TryAddScoped(" + typeToAdd + "," + c.Name + ")");
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  // Only add the concrete class
                  // For now just use scoped service lifetime
                  services.TryAddScoped(type.AsType());
                  logger?.LogInformation(LogEventIDs.Information_General_ID, "INFORMATION: A new Service Class Was Added: services.TryAddScoped(" + typeToAdd + ")");
                }
                isTypeFound = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            // If users added types in the enum lists
            // thats not found, flag as a warning!
            if (!isTypeFound)
            {
              missingEnumTypes.Add(typeToAdd);
            }
           }
           // If a bad enum service name was added, log that as a warning.
           if (missingEnumTypes.Count > 0)
           {
             string items = string.Empty;
             foreach (string s in missingEnumTypes)
             {
               if (items != string.Empty) items += " | ";
               items += s;
             }
             logger?.LogWarning(LogEventIDs.Warning_General_ID, "WARNING: These Types/Interfaces/Classes added to Services were not found in the application >>> " + items);
           }
        }
    }
```

Register Services consumes the enum list of Services and Consumers above.

The last step is to call the method above inside your Startup.cs .NET file in Core. Add `RegisterServices.Start()` static method call with your *ConfigureServices* class inside `Startup.cs` in the root of your .NET Core application. I also add the logger as a parameter but this version just use the services parameter. "services" is whatever the parameter is in your
*ConfigureServices* method in Startup.cs:

```
RegisterServices.Start(services);
```

**HOW TO USE DEPENDENCY INJECTION**

After you run `RegisterServices` in your .NET application and Startup.cs calls it, all your services (and child classes derived from interfaces) are now registered!

To call a Service and have it auto-implemented when you instantiate a class in .NET appears to be inconsistent. The IoC Container will auto-inject all constructor services in MVC `Controllers`, for example, but NOT regular classes. To solve that I recommend you try and inject everything into your controllers, then use the `IServiceProvider` in regular class constructors to help you auto-inject all other classes with the services they need (see below).

If you are in ASP.NET Core, your best strategy is to ALWAYS add each service to your controller's constructor using interfaces. You can then have full access to every service you need or any service a child object inside the controller might need. But there will be times you have classes you call outside the controllers that inject services but are not auto-injected. So below are some examples of how to do that and still honor the dependency injection model.

*Note: If you are an expert at this, please suggest below in comments how I can improve on this idea, as this is the best model I have for now that is simple and easy to use.*

```
    // HOW TO USE SERVICES?

    // CONTROLLERS (Web Applications)
    // Always inject the services you need into the controller's constructor.
    // The IoC Container in .NET always auto-injects these objects 
    // for you and are 100% ready to access. If using ASP.NET, always use the
    // constructor of the controller to inject services.

    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
      private readonly ISampleService _myservice;
      public HomeController(ISampleService myservice){
        _myservice = myservice;
      }
      // You can now access your "_myservice" in any action method of the controller
    }

    // NON-CONTROLLERS and NON-INJECTED CONSTRUCTORS
    // If you cant inject the service object into an ASP.NET Controller 
    // but still need to instantiate the object, your best alternative
    // is to inject the ServiceProvider into your Controller or Class 
    // constructor first. IoC auto-injects the service collection
    // so you can now access it to create child objects you can
    // tell .NET to auto-inject with their own services when created
    // using the registered services in your enum as an example.

    public MyClass (IServiceProvider myservice) {
      // Here are 3 ways to force the IoC to auto-inject your dependencies
      var obj1 = myservice.GetService<SampleService>();
      var obj2 = myservice.GetService(SampleService) as ISampleService;
      var obj3 = myservice.GetRequiredService(SampleService) as ISampleService;
      var obj4 = (SampleService)myservice.GetService(typeof(SampleService));
    }
```

Below is one of the Service Interface types in the enum above and the child classes that got registered which are now available to use as services in the code above after running the `RegisterServices` call:

```
    // SERVICE INTERFACE
    public interface ISampleService
    {
        void Message(string message);
    }

    // SERVICE CONCRETE CLASS
    class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        public void Message(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
        }
    }

    // SERVICE CONCRETE CLASS
    class AnotherSampleService : ISampleService
    {
        public void Message(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use factory to achieve that.

```
services.AddScoped(provider =>
{
    //Resolve some service at runtime.
    var aService = provider.GetService<AServiceType>();
    //Any synchronous logic here
    return new MyDynamicService();
});
```

Comment: This is resolving a service, not registering.