# How to inject in parallel dependencies into my AspNetCore ICollection services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, task-parallel-library

Currently I have into my ConfigureServices all the dependencies I inject

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
     //injecting my dependenies here
     services.AddDependencies(Configuration);
 }
```

The thing is that I want to optimize the process below injecting things in parallel. Please see that what I want to optimize is the processing time of this method **AddDependencies**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDependencies(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
  services.RegisterTypes(configuration)
            .AddFluentValidationConfiguration()
            .AddAutomapperConfiguration();

  return services;
}
```

My approach at first was the following:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDependencies(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var t1 = Task.Run(() => { services.RegisterTypes(configuration);});
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => { services.RegisterFluentValidation();});
        var t3 = Task.Run(() => { services.RegisterMappingsWithAutomapper();});

        Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3).Wait();

        return services;
    }
```

But sometimes I get an exception, my methods like RegisterTypes internally make calls like this

```
services.Register<ISmtpConfig, SmtpConfig>(lifeTime);
```

so the resource `services` is shared between multiple threads, I thought that putting a lock statement similar to this would fix the problem, but no

```
 private Object thisLock = new Object(); --> global variable  

 lock (thisLock)  
 {  
   services.Register<ISmtpConfig, SmtpConfig>(lifeTime);
 }
```

Can anyone put me into the right spot?

Comment: This is not the part where dependencies get injected you just register them and you do not need to do that in tasks since this is executed only once.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You encounter a problem X, assume Y is the solution and when that fails you ask about Y, not X. You don't need tasks to register services. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: DI must be done sequentially before processing requests, why do you want to inject them paralleled?  do you think it could improve a lot of performance?

Comment: @alsami, you are right, but every time the application pools recycles, then is done again.

Comment: The `IServiceCollection` collection isn't thread-safe. It can't be - the order of the calls matters. Even with lock statements in *all* methods, registration will run sequentially but in random order

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not assuming is the solutions, I tested on the past, and I know it drops my times considerably. I am just asking what can be happening with my code, and rather than that if I am using correctly the threads to avoid a deadlock situation

Comment: Doesn't change a thing. These registrations do not even take nano seconds to proceed.

Comment: @Heinrich Tasks offer nothing here. Registration is *not* slow so it doesn't need parallel processing.

Comment: @Dongdong not the performance on the application overall, the performance on the processing time while injecting the dependencies, I am optimizing that time, not when the container resolves its objects per request

Comment: @Heinrich why? Why do you think that *registration* is slow? Did you measure it with a profiler or did you assume it's the case? If it's slow, you'll have to find out what's wrong. Do you have eg a slow database configuration provider?

Comment: @Heinrich it seems the X you are trying to solve is cold-start time. There are other solutions for this. Registration is typically *far* faster than eg JIT compilation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I measure the time with the dotrace, and with Threads it drops the time considerably

Comment: @Heinrich and breaks the application. What did you see in dotTrace? Which is the slow method? Why is it slow in the first place?

Comment: @Heinrich I'll have to repeat it. ServiceCollection isn't thread-safe. You'll have to use a lock statement inside *all* Tasks, forcing them to run sequentially. If you want to improve performance you'll have to find which method is slow and why

Comment: AddDependencies has RegisterTypes that load things from an assembly and I later do some reflection over it and automapper and fluentvalidation can run and inject the things without that information, basically they don't relate each other, that's another reason for doing it in parallel

Comment: @Heinrich which means the *reflection* code needs to run faster, not the DI registration. How many assemblies are you using? Perhaps you can *exclude* those that aren't needed

Comment: I am starting a chat here for further discussion [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177116/discussion-between-heinrich-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I move the discussion to a chat

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is not the place where you can improve something by adding dependencies in parallel.
Practically, this configuration method runs once on application start. In my sample project (in Debug mode inside Visual Studio), it takes less than a second. At the second run (just to be sure that it is JITed already) like 6ms. And VS reduces performance dramatically (700ms vs 300ms on first run).
So, I would suggest you put stopwatch into the begin of `ConfigureServices()` method and put something like

```
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Service initialization took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

in the end.

Maybe you can give more clues about performance issues you have?

Comment: this is something I did it on the past, it improves the performance by far if you are loading assemblies and doing reflection to inject some stuff you mark, of course is doesn't take a minute, but it drops my times considerably.

Comment: Maybe you can shed a light on details? How long it takes? Why you need a reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance issue is: so many classes need to be loaded at the beginning, and all classes are from different assemblies, which will force web server to load them to memory. but they should be register & loaded on demand, you can follow this post to implement it:
[C# Dependency Injection Runtime (dynamic) registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262766/c-sharp-dependency-injection-runtime-dynamic-registration)