# Resolving dependency by parameter - without pre instantiating services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Simplification, I have this simple code :

```
    services.AddScoped<IFruit>(provider =>
        {
            var httpContext = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

            if (httpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
            {
                return new AppleService(...);
            }
            else return new OrangeService(...);
        });
```

Problem is that `AppleService` & `OrangeSservice` has many( and different) parameters in constructor ( other DI parameters) , and I think I'm going the wrong direction here.

```
public class AppleService:IFruit
{
 public  AppleService (a,b,c,d,e....){}
}

public class OrangeService:IFruit
{
 public  OrnageService (o,i,u,y,....){}
}
```

Also, I don't want to pre-instantiate both services only to decide which to go to.

I want that instantiation will only be for the service which I'm about to use . ( according to request parameters)

However , I've seen a nice solution ( using factory) in the following [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40655495/859154), But as you can see he injects and instantiate both services even if he only needs one.

(in my scenario I need Scoped instantiation)

[image]

**Question:**

How can I instantiate *only* the service I need per request params?

Comment: I can think of a few ways to make this happen, but you basic approach is probably a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a lot of parameters if you registered your services into the DI container and then use the `ServiceProvider` to resolve them.

This way you don't need to instantiate the services manually.

```cs
services.AddScoped<AppleService>();
services.AddScoped<OrangeService>();
services.AddScoped<IFruit>(provider =>
{
    var httpContext = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    if (httpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
    {
        return provider.GetRequiredService<AppleService>();
    }

    return provider.GetRequiredService<OrangeService>();
});
```

Comment: Scoped services seem to behave like singletons in their scopes. They are not instantiated until they are needed, but after that they are always the same instances. 

I just tried this with the basic ValuesController, on GET an I need an OrangeService, on post, an AppleService. I put a logger in both of the services constructor, and the result was this:

https://imgur.com/a/IolMYiq

Comment: So this `services.AddScoped<OrangeService>();` doesn't instantiate it ,  as opposed to `provider.GetRequiredService<AppleService>()` which does instantaiate them ?

Comment: Yes. The instantiation happens not when you add the class to the ServiceCollection, but when you use the ServiceProvider to get an instance of the class. Seems reasonable, I mean if you have 30 classes in your DI container it's not necessary to instantiate each one of them per request.