# Best strategy for creating a child container (or isolated scope) with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

In my AspNetCore application, I process messages that arrive from a queue. In order to process a message, I need to resolve some services. Some of those services have a dependency on `ITenantId`, which I bind using information from the received message. To solve this, the processing of a messages starts with the creation of a child container, which I then use to create an [IServiceScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) from which I resolve all the needed dependencies.

The messages can be processed in parallel, so the scopes must be isolated from each other.

I can see to ways of creating the child container, but I'm not sure which is best in terms of performance, memory chrurn etc:

Option A: Each time a message arrives, clone the IServiceCollection into a new ServiceCollection, and rebind `ITenantId` on the cloned instance.

Option B: When the program starts, create an immutable copy of the IServiceCollection (using `ImmutableList<ServiceDescriptor>` or `ImmutableArray<ServiceDescriptor>`). Each time a message arrives, replace `ITenantId` (resulting in a new instance of `ImmutableList<ServiceDescriptor>`) and call `CreateScope()` on the new immutable instance.

The thing I don't like about option A is that the whole collection of services needs to be cloned every time a message arrives. I'm not sure if the immutable collections in option B handles this in a smarter way?

Comment: Consider not using (any) DI Container as mechanism to separate state specific to tenants. As doing this will lead to "magic" where some services will be state aware, and some not (without transparent indication as to why), as well as inefficiencies where if you want to perform operations over multiple tenants, you'll have to create a lot of scopes. Instead you could use a cache that has "region/tenant" support built in.

However thank you for asking this question, I find ability to create child containers useful e.g. in test automation, to create a cloned child container per parallel thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both options cause the creation of a new container instance for each incoming messages. Although this allows each message to run in a completely isolated bubble, this has severe implications on performance and memory use of the application. Creating container instances is expensive and resolving a registered instance for the first time (per container) causes generation of expression trees, compilation of delegates, and JIT compiling them. This can even cause memory leaks.

Besides, it also means that any registered singleton class will have a lifetime that equals that of any scoped classes. State can't be shared any longer.

So instead, I propose Option 3:

- Use only one Container instance and don't call `BuildProvider` more than once
- Create a `ITenantId` implementation that allows setting the `Id` after instantiation
- Register that implementation as `Scoped`
- At the start of every new `IServiceScope`, resolve that implementation and set its id.

This might look as follows:

```cs
// Code
class TenentIdImpl : ITenantId
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // settable
}

// Startup:
services.AddScoped<TenentIdImpl>();
services.AddScoped<ITenantId>(c => c.GetRequiredService<TenantIdImpl>());

// In message pipeline
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var tenant = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TenantIdImpl>();
    tenant.Id = messageEnvelope.TenantId;

    var handler =
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMessageHandler<TMessage>>();

    handler.Handle(messageEnvelope.Message);
}
```

This particular model, where you store state inside your object graph, which I explain in my blog, is what I call the [Closure Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/closure-composition-model/).

Comment: Thats a good idea! You still get isolation since TenentIdImpl is unique to each scope. I'll try this out later today. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanna get back to you and confirm that this worked perfectly. One question though: how come it's called the closure composition model? I can't see that it relies on closure in the usual sense, where the runtime would close over a set of fields/variables available to a function. From what I can tell, it rather relies on the fact that ITenantId and ITenantIdImpl are bound as scoped.

Comment: The Closure Composition Model describes a model where variables are wrapped and stored inside a containing class, much like how a functional closure works, compared to the Ambient Composition Model, where data is stored outside a class, but rather in stored and retrieved from ambient state. You might the use of the term "closure" more intuitive when the runtime value is injected through the constructor, but this is something that is actually quite hard to achieve when using a DI Cotainer.